# Flutter : gradle issue

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Arif\apps\flutter-training\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle' line: 4
- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0']

> No implementation class specified for plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin' in jar:file:/C:/Users/Arif/.gradle/caches/jars-9/f6488a8a75cc22a1f16673e4c5ef9abb/gradle-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin.properties.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

what is the error here? I'm new on the Flutter and trying to setup

and here a message like that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDvNy.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.